# Rewrite site with first slash to index

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm sorry about the title but I can't find a good one to explain what I try to do.
I have my website : http://domaine.com .
The index.php file in it redirect to http://domaine.com/views/index.php .

Now I want to Rewrite Rule so that any url like :
http://domaine.com/something display the site http://domaine.com so that :

```
http://domaine.com/php redirect http://domaine.com/php/views/index.php
http://domaine.com/java redirect http://domaine.com/java/views/index.php
http://domaine.com/ruby redirect http://domaine.com/ruby/views/index.php
```

etc.

EDIT : I'm working on localhost so it's supposed to:

```
localhost/formation/php => localhost/formation/php/views/index.php
localhost/formation/java => localhost/formation/java/views/index.php
localhost/formation/ruby => localhost/formation/ruby/views/index.php
```

EDIT : The content of my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ views/index.php [L,QSA]
```

When I access to localhost/formation/ruby/ for exemple it's working but after the loggin it look like it's always redirecting from the home page to login page to home page etc.

EDIT : I create a repertory called "ruby" and create in it a htaccess file with that content.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ../$1 [L]
```

And it does exactly what I want. So I want to find a way to do that without having to create the repertory "ruby".

Comment: `http://domaine.com/java/views/index.php` looks strange (Java or PHP?)

Comment: PHP .. It was juste an example of url but I am working on PHP

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> http://domaine.com/php redirect http://domaine.com/php/views/index.php
> http://domaine.com/java redirect http://domaine.com/java/views/index.php
> http://domaine.com/ruby redirect http://domaine.com/ruby/views/index.php
> ```

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(php|java|ruby)/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /%1/views/index.php
```

I suppose by "redirect" you mean "serve as". In case if you want a 301 redirect, use the appropriate flags for `RewriteRule`, e.g. `[R=301,L]`.

**Wrapper**

In case if you are trying to implement a wrapper script which is supposed to handle different request URIs, you should process the requests with a single script and pass the URI path parts as query string parameters. For instance:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(formation|another_type)/(php|java|ruby)/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /wrapper.php?type=%1&lang=%2
```

With this configuration, you can handle requests like `http://your-site.com/formation/ruby/` with a single script. You can access the query string parameters using the `$_GET` superglobal variable, e.g. `echo $_GET['lang'];`.

Ultimately, you can process *all* requests with a single wrapper:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wrapper.php
```

Within the wrapper you will have to examine the contents of the `$_SERVER` superglobal. The `REQUEST_URI` and `REQUEST_URI` values are particularly useful.

Comment: I got : The requested URL /formation/php/ was not found on this server.

Comment: I see nothing about `/formation/` in your question.

Comment: Yes SORRY @Ruslan. I edit the question. It's because I'm working on localhost.

Comment: @arshie92, then `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/formation/(php|java|ruby)/$` and `RewriteRule ^.*$ /formation/%1/views/index.php`, similarly

Comment: I got the same message : The requested URL /formation/php was not found on this server.

Comment: @arshie92, suppose the server's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is `/www/site.com/public`, then you should have file `/www/site.com/public/formation/php/views/index.php` available on the file system as well as `/www/site.com/public/formation/java/views/index.php`

Comment: yes I see. But is there a way to do that without have to create that files. Because I dont want to create a file for each formation.

Comment: @arshie92, I've updated the answer. Then you have to redirect the requests to a single wrapper script

Comment: I'm sorry but I never heard about wrapper script. So I have to create a wrapper.php file and write a script in it. Wright ? You can see my edit to please.

Comment: @arshie92, a "wrapper" is just a normal PHP script that determines the requested URI by examining such variables as `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. This is the way to create search-engine-friendly URLs, by the way. Check it out. Create `/www/site.com/public/wrapper.php` like `<?php var_dump($_SERVER); ` and use the rules at the end of the answer.

Comment: And how to redirect using this wrapper file. What kind of script can I use please.

Comment: @arshie92, you are _not_ using wrapper PHP file for redirection. The `wrapper.php` processes _all_ requests. `RewriteRule ^.*$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wrapper.php` forwards _any_ request to the script (`/a/b/c/d/e/f/anything`). Test wrapper: `<?php var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

Comment: Thanks. I got it. So now I have to know how to use the script to display the good content. @Ruslan

Comment: Sorry @Ruslan but if you can please check my last edit, maybe you have a solution for that.